# rails activerecords query, row splitting

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

i have some records like this one

```
"boss/supervisor/employee"
"boss"
"boss/supervisor"
```

i would like to put all this records in a select input without repeating themselves... here is what i've done already

in my index i did this:

```
@jerarquy = Jerarquy.uniq.pluck(:name)
```

so when i get all the records from the column jerarquy:

```
<select>
    <% @jerarquy.each do |jer| %>
        <% jer.split('/').each do |j| %>
            <option><%= j %></option>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</select>
```

i do get the data from the database but i think i have to change something in my controller in order to get the information i want in the order i want, for example if i select a boss i want to get /supervisor and /employee too but if i select a employee i want to only get a employee

Comment: You'll have to be more specific, do you want to split the string on "/"? It would probably help if you specified the desired HTML output. Jerarquy  means Hierarchy right?

Comment: yes and i would like to have a select input with all the data from that column without repeating it

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would use flatten to convert the fields to a single array and then use `.uniq`

```
ary = ["boss/supervisor/employee", "boss", "boss/supervisor"]
ary.map { |string| string.split('/') }.flatten.uniq
=> ["boss", "supervisor", "employee"]
```

---

```
@jerarquy = Jerarquy.uniq.pluck(:name).map { |string| string.split('/') }.flatten.uniq

<select>
    <% @jerarquy.each do |jer| %>        
      <option><%= j %></option>
    <% end %>
</select>
```

However I would say that this code indicates a poor underlying design. 
You should be letting the database handle pulling out unique records.

Comment: +1 on the solution, however I agree on the note about improving the design. Slicing the roles (?) out into separate table, with some associations or whatever would be a lot better in terms of design, both in database and application layer.